# How to find the second last indexof a value in a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string referrer = "?404;http://stage.hello.com:80/Applications/";

referrer = referrer.Substring(referrer.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

By doing this I get referrer value `""` as answer.

I want my referrer value to be "Applications/"

How can I achieve this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
referrer = referrer.Substring(referrer.Substring(0, referrer.LastIndexOf("/")).LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

First variant:

```
referrer = Regex.Match(referrer, @"(?!/)[^/]*/[^/]*$").Value;
```

Second variant:

```
referrer = string.Join("/", referrer.Split('/').Reverse().Take(2).Reverse());
```

Comment: c# 8.0 Ranges: `string.Join("/", referrer.Split('/')[^2..]);`

Answer (score 3):

The unsafe variant (if you are sure there are at least 2 occurences of the value in the string) would be like this

```
string referrer = "?404;http://stage.hello.com:80/Applications/";
referrer = referrer.Substring(referrer.LastIndexOf("/", referrer.LastIndexOf("/") - 1) + 1);
```

The safe version is like this

```
int lastIndex = referrer.LastIndexOf("/");
int secondLastIndex = lastIndex > 0 ? referrer.LastIndexOf("/", lastIndex - 1) : -1;
if (secondLastIndex >= 0)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```